# Make Laravel Homestead Accessible via the Internet

Tags: networking, laravel, vagrant

How can I make Laravel Homestead (a Vagrant vm) accessible via the internet? Currently, I have set my router to port-forward to my host machine's local IP. However, that causes the Laravel site to think that all incoming requests are coming from 10.0.2.2.

What would be the correct way to make the site accessible via the internet? Would I have to get the VM to be assigned an IP from the routers DHCP? If so, how do I do that?

Comment: Homestead shouldn't be used for any serious hosting. For showing it to a friend/client/etc., consider https://ngrok.com/

Comment: I'm well aware, it is for sharing with only a few individuals. I have a dev subdomain set up and pointing to my WAN IP. I also have it set to only allow access from certain IP addresses. But the problem remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer these days would be to use Homestead's `share` alias on the command line via ssh.

eg. `share acme.app`

Behind the scenes, this uses [ngrok](https://ngrok.com) and is documented in the [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/homestead#sharing-your-environment).

Answer (score 0):

You can make it work with [xip.io](http://xip.io/) service. More details here: http://christoph-rumpel.com/2014/10/access-laravel-homestead-projects-through-other-devices-in-three-little-steps/

Comment: This seems like more of a hack approach and produces a horrible URL, I'd rather set it up as a sub-domain on my own domain. Is there not a way to get the vagrant machine to be assigned an IP from my router?

Comment: No, but you don't really need that - use your machine's IP with port 8000 (assuming default homestead configuration). http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/homestead#ports

Answer (score 0):

Chances are you need to tell Laravel to trust the router as a proxy:

```
Request::setTrustedProxies([
    '10.0.2.2',
]);
```

This will work *if* the router correctly sets `X-Forwarded-For` sort of headers.

Comment: ceejayoz, what is du?

Comment: @user1960364 Sorry, looks like I started typing something and hit enter accidentally.