# Laravel Homestead Accessible via the Internet and CORS issue

Tags: cors, vagrant, homestead, ngrok

I followed the steps on [Make Laravel Homestead Accessible via the Internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27283199/make-laravel-homestead-accessible-via-the-internet) and was able to connect.

on the `.env` file, I have added following

```
DEFAULT_SITE_URL="public url created by ngrok/"
```

Thereafter facing the CORS issue with my local assets as follows

> Access to font at '*public url to local assets*' from origin '*vagrant
>   IP for local*' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

What is the best way to get rid.